# Typescript: Can't index an array that is being returned from a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to index an array that is being constructed and returned from a function but I am given the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '3' can't be used to index type 'ArrFunc'.
  Property '3' does not exist on type 'ArrFunc'
```

This is the code I have recreated on Typescript playground to show my issue.

```
type ArrFunc = () => number[];
const arrFunc:ArrFunc = () => [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(arrFunc[3]);
```

I am unsure which "Element implicitly has an 'any' type." As far as I can tell, everything in the above example is pretty well defined.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

An array is *returned* from `arrFunc`, so you can only access elements from the array after you call the function.

```
console.log(arrFunc()[3]);
```

Comment: Yeah haha, I realised as soon as my question posted. Thank you for your swift answer!

Answer (score 1):

So dumb....

Obviously I can not index a function. For this to work the function must be called.

```
const arr = arrFunc();
console.log(arr[3])  // No problem
```

How embarrassing :D